# Why three different versions of PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, zend-server-ce

Why have the PHP teams got three different stable versions of PHP on the go? These are: 5.6, 5.5, 5.4, and they've just recently released version 7 alpha.

Could someone enlighten me as to why the PHP group decided that three different stable versions of PHP is good idea? And might I assume that I best just jump straight into 5.7 and clean up my code?

I don't think my requirements are exotic - I don't crunch data, I just use PHP validated data to read/write to MySQL - no rocket science.

The issue? My old WAMP Zend v6 Community Edition run's PHP 5.5.7 and my *new* AWS micro machine uses 5.3.29 (build date May 2015 but amazingly, AWS have standardized on the pre-historic 5.3).  I discovered a bug with `json_encode()`. When I realised I have two different versions of PHP, I'm thinking its best I just upgrade both to similar versions. Hence I am thinking 5.7 is probably my best bet for future support. Comments welcome.

Comment: because there's enough users of the "old" versions that can't (or won't) upgrade to newer versions due to deprecrated/removed features. in other words, you might as well ask Microsoft why they supported XP for so long when Vista and 7 were also available.

Comment: @cmorrissey Okay - that makes sense... Thanks for prompt reply.

Comment: Because they decided a while back on rules for maintaining support of older versions that didn't entail having to support 10 or 15 or 20 different versions - http://php.net/supported-versions.php - but PHP 5.4 is security patches only now (and only for another 2 months before it's no longer supported at all), PHP 5.5 will become security patches only in just a few more days, and PHP 5.7 will never exist

Comment: one reason is what Marc B said, the other reason why they do this is to correct their mistakes in previous versions,for example let's take a look to CSS.CSS2  was not fully implemented in browsers so that led the CSS team to create new versions: CSS 2.1 and CSS3.same happened with HTML.HTML2.0(released in 1995)was Not **forward** looking at all!Followed by that, HTML 3.2, Web Standard Project, HTML 4.0, XHTML and so on were released.

Comment: @MarkB you say PHP 5.7 will never exist, true - I meant to say 5.6... I was going to point out your typo, but instead found my own. Thanks =) I guess I will standardize on 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The older versions are less supported than the newer versions however the older versions exist because of their popularity within present day production.